# Phaser: how to display another map using the json file?

Tags: javascript, json, phaser-framework, game-development, tiled

### Context

I am working under [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) (which is a Javascript Framework for game development) and I followed [this](https://gamedevacademy.org/how-to-make-a-mario-style-platformer-with-phaser-3/?a=13) totorial. All the code works perfectly. But to make the map the tutorial use a `.json` file which content a `data` part in order to display the map.

[image: screenshot]

---

### Problem

I would like to change the map and display my own map. Here is the `map.json` that display the map:

```js
{ "backgroundcolor":"#000000",
 "height":10,
 "infinite":false,
 "layers":[
        {
         "data":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8AAAAPAAAADwAAAA8AAAAPAAAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8AAAAPAAAADwAAAA8AAAAPAAAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwAAAA8AAAAPAAAADwAAAA8AAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAAAwAAAAMAAAADAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAABQAAAAUAAAAFAAAA",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":10,
         "name":"World",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":30,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextobjectid":31,
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tiledversion":"2018.03.21",
 "tileheight":70,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "columns":4,
         "firstgid":1,
         "image":"tiles.png",
         "imageheight":280,
         "imagewidth":280,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"tiles",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":16,
         "tileheight":70,
         "tilewidth":70
        }, 
        {
         "columns":1,
         "firstgid":17,
         "image":"coinGold.png",
         "imageheight":70,
         "imagewidth":70,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"coin",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":1,
         "tileheight":70,
         "tilewidth":70
        }],
 "tilewidth":70,
 "type":"map",
 "version":1.2,
 "width":30
}
```

I know that the part used in order to display the map is `layers.data`.

**What are these letters all about?** Is is a kind of special format that I never heard about so far?

**How can I should I know which letters correspond to which tiles?**

*If you need more informations or if you have any question please let me know, thanks !*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That map was made using [Tiled](https://www.mapeditor.org/) which allows you to make tiled maps using a set of tiles (aka sprites). Exporting it in json allows you to import it into game engines with ease, in this case, Phaser.

Doing these by hand could be troublesome so a tilemap editor like Tiles helps you accelerate your map development. You can also create and place each tile programmatically but it would depend on which type of game you're aiming at.

[here's](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-tiled-map-editor-a-platform-agnostic-tool-for-level-maps--gamedev-2838) an introductory tutorial on how to use Tiled to create a map. Be sure to save it as json instead of .tmx so you can import it in phaser.